# Quantifier change: from exist to forall?

Tags: proof-verification, predicate-logic

For instance, I want to prove ;

> $\exists xp(x) \vdash \forall y p(y)$

is valid.

Can the proof itself be valid? And what the idea behind this proof stands for?

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely not valid. Think about it: you are basically saying "Since something has property P, everything has property P". For example, "Since 2 is an even number, everything is an even number"??!?

Comment: but we are changing the variable name, which means we are passing from x's space to y's space. Could not we suppose y's are the subset of x's?

Comment: @onurctirtir No. Whenever we consider the logical relationships between several statements, we use the same domain for each of the statements. So there is no '$x$-domain' or '$y$-domain'.  Also, the $x$'s and $y$'s are just dummy variables, so $\exists x P(x)$ is the exact same statement as $\exists y P(y)$.